# Using ParseError Django REST Framework to return invalid data

Tags: django, rest, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I have a similar issue as this question about validating data in the Django REST Framework outside of a serializer:

[Raise Validation Error In Pre_Save Using Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726789/raise-validation-error-in-pre-save-using-django-rest-framework)

My code:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    data = self.request.DATA['users']
    for user in data:
        if not user in allowed_users:
            raise ParseError('An unpermitted user has been included')
```

From the trace it looks like it's trying to send the response but it fails with:

"" needs to have a value for field before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

UPDATE:

I moved raising the ParseError into a get_serializer_class() method like so:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if 'users' in self.request.DATA:
        # make sure the users are allowed
        data = self.request.DATA['users']
        for user in data:
            if not user in allowed_users:
                raise ParseError(detail='Unpermitted user')
    return serializer
```

And this raises the exception, however, it does not return it using the REST framework's JSON response. Rather I get the django stack trace and a 500 error, which is not good.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the exception is raised in the pre_save method(), post_save(), or even in a post() method for the viewclass, it was being handled correctly by Django-REST-Framework. Had I been using curl or similar, the error would have been returned correctly.

This actually is a bug in the browsable API, which is what I was using to test - sending the data using the "Raw data" form. When trying to render the html response, DRF apparently tries to capture the "context" of the post. In this case, it wanted the saved/completed post.

That did not exist, so a Django rendering error was being thrown and that confused me.

When testing using curl, the response was accurate.

Note that putting it in the get_serializer_class() like I did caused it to go outside of the DRF exception handler so Django rendered it correctly and showed the error was being thrown correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`APIView`'s `handle_exception`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views#handle_exceptionself-exc) — this is where DRF processes exceptions raised during the request.

From the docs:

> The default implementation handles any subclass of `rest_framework.exceptions.APIException`, as well as Django's `Http404` and `PermissionDenied` exceptions, and returns an appropriate error response.
>
> If you need to customize the error responses your API returns you should subclass this method.

So you need to override this to handle `ParseError` exceptions too.

Also check out the DRF docs on [Exceptions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Carlton. Looks like the problem has more to do with the Browsable API.